# How to acces @Composable property within composable?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose, composable

Assume I have a Jetpack composable:

```
Column(modifier = Modifier.height(48.dp)) {
    // stuff
    
    // access above modifier here?
    
    //more stuff
}
```

I added a Modifier to the Column above.

As pointed out: **How can I access the Modifier within that Column?**

Comment: `Column()` is a function, not a class, and `modifier` is a function parameter, not a property. AFAIK, you have no access to the modifier unless for some reason the function exposes that in whatever the receiver is of its trailing lambda (where you have your comments). If your objective is to modify the height, have the height be driven by a `MutableState` and modify that state, to force recomposition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, the `Column` is a function, and `modifier` is a function parameter.
If you want to use modifier in the `Column`，like this:

```kotlin
val modifierColumn = Modifier.height(48.dp)
Column(modifier = modifierColumn) {
    // stuff

    // access above modifier here?
    Text("Hello Compose!",modifier = modifierColumn)
    //more stuff
}
```